# How to implement a minimal mock of a polymorphic method in Scala?

Tags: scala, mocking

Say I have the following trait and class:

```scala
case class Result[A](
    header: String,
    data: A
)

trait WebClient {
  def doSomething[A : TypeTag](name: String): Future[Result[A]]
}
```

In this example, `doSomething` is the [polymorphic method](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html) in question. How can I create a `MockWebClient` which implements `WebClient` and have minimal behavior? (The most minimal behavior being doing nothing.) Preferably, I don't want to return a `Future.failed` because the result shouldn't signify a failure, semantically. Also, I don't want to change the `A` type of `Result[A]` to be [covariant or contravariant](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html) (i.e. `+A` or `-A`) because it doesn't make a lot of sense in the context.

Here's my best attempt (which still doesn't compile). It uses a generic class with a generic factory to simulate the return value of the `doSomething` method. However, I cannot find the correct relationship between `A` and `B`:

```scala
class MockWebClient[A](val factory: () => Result[A]) extends WebClient {
  override def doSomething[B >: A : TypeTag](name: String): Future[Result[B]] = {
    Future.successful(factory())
  }
}
```

Also, I have used `mockito-scala`, but it doesn't work because of type erasure. `scalamock` also seems interesting, but I would like to know if there is a way to make something similar to my solution work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure `data` field will not be used in the test you could trick the compiler with `null.asInstanceOf[A]`

```
val mockWebClient = new WebClient {
  override def doSomething[A](name: String): Future[Result[A]] =
    Future.successful(Result(name, null.asInstanceOf[A]))
}
```

If `A` forms a `Monoid` you could do it in a type-safe manner with something like

```
import cats.Monoid
import cats.implicits._

trait WebClient {
  def doSomething[A: Monoid](name: String): Future[Result[A]]
}

val mockWebClient = new WebClient {
  override def doSomething[A: Monoid](name: String): Future[Result[A]] =
    Future.successful(Result(name, implicitly[Monoid[A]].empty))
}

mockWebClient.doSomething[String]("woohoo")
```

Comment: I would just make a class that receives in the constructor the value to be returned.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That would be great, but how do you reconcile / equate the type `B` in polymorphic method `doSomething[B]` with generic type `A` in `MockWebClient[A]`?

Comment: @krismath oh right, I didn't checked this that carefully. How does even the production implementation of such trait is able to produce any `A` from nowhere?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `A` needs to be specified explicitly during the method call.

Comment: @krismath that wasn't the question, the question is if I ask for a **String** how does it produce one? if I ask for a **Map[String, Int]**, how does it produces one?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah, actually there is another context-bound for `A` that specifies how to produce that `A`. It is spray-json `JsonFormat` (i.e. `[A : TypeTag : JsonFormat]`). I am under the impression that this have significant impact on the question though.

Comment: @krismath yeah you may think then in using that formatted to validate if the requested type is the same that you passed in the constructor or not.